# lines as columns rows into 2D array | python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on file type called .pdb, I want to insert these lines in a 2D array? (file is better than shown here) later I want to retrieve those characters (eg: HO2' A 10.000 03') separately,
could you help me to design 2D arrays, I'm very new to python. Thanks

```
ATOM     64 HO2'   A     2      10.090   1.313   5.546  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     65  O3'   A     2       9.461  -1.229   8.060  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM     66  P     G     3       8.676  -0.774   9.370  1.00  0.00           P  
ATOM     67  OP1   G     3       9.541  -0.969  10.560  1.00  0.00           O
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a fixed-width format, so the best solution is probably to manually give the field widths.

However, if we want to do something quick-and-dirty, we could just split on whitespace, like so:

```
import re

with open('file.pdb', 'r') as file:
  arr = [ re.split("[ \t\r\n]+", line) for line in file ]
```

Here the string `"[ \t\r\n]+"` is a regular expression matching one or more whitespace characters -- spaces, tabs, carriage returns, or newlines.

If `file.pdb` contains the text above then the result is like so:

```
[
  ['ATOM', '64', "HO2'", 'A', '2', '10.090', '1.313', '5.546', '1.00', '0.00', 'H', ''],
  ['ATOM', '65', "O3'", 'A', '2', '9.461', '-1.229', '8.060', '1.00', '0.00', 'O', ''],
  ['ATOM', '66', 'P', 'G', '3', '8.676', '-0.774', '9.370', '1.00', '0.00', 'P', ''],
  ['ATOM', '67', 'OP1', 'G', '3', '9.541', '-0.969', '10.560', '1.00', '0.00', 'O', '']
]
```

Note that we have an empty field at the end of each line.  This occurs because there's whitespace at the end of the lines, "separating" the last field from... nothing.

This may not be a problem for you, but if it is you can remove it easily enough, e.g. by replacing

```
re.split("[ \t\r\n]+", line)
```

with

```
re.split("[ \t\r\n]+", line)[:-1]
```

which says to take the sublist starting at the beginning of the list and ending one before the end.

Comment: This code works fine for me, 
The final array is like arr=[ [] [] [] , [] [] [] [] ] one line 2D array,
How can I get these line as x[] and colums as Y[] 
I would love to learn a way through two if/while loops , Thanks